# Rebuild indexes but still fragmented

Tags: sql-server

I have a script to rebuild or reorganize the indexes but after checking again, some indexes were still sitting at over 90% fragmentation.  I've read different suggestions that involved the page fragment count, free space in the DB etc.  Just not sure what else to check or how to conclusively know that the index maintenance has had a positive effect.

Comment: The guideline I often see is that if the page count for an index is < 1000, there's not a great need to reorganize or rebuild it.  It's a guideline, though, not a rule.  Here's some additional info:  http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/where-do-the-books-online-index-fragmentation-thresholds-come-from/

Comment: I think ive seen mention of that also.  It just seems that if a "rebuild" on an index is done, it should remove the fragmentation regardless of how many pages it has.  Seem reasonable?  Maybe I'm missing something, but internally does the engine ignore indexes below a certain page count?

Comment: Also, which specific page count attribute are you referring to? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187737(v=sql.90).aspx  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190283.aspx