# Index still fragmented right after rebuilding it (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I noticed that even though I rebuild an index with e.g.

```
ALTER INDEX IX_WeeklyData_SP_ID ON dbo.WeeklyData
REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON) ;
```

it still remains fragmented. I noticed this strange thing a few times already.
I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1).

Why is that? Shouldn't this action (rebuilding the index)
immediately decrease the index fragmentation percentage
(to some value close to 0)?

I noticed this question here (which seems identical)

[Rebuild indexes but still fragmented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714542/rebuild-indexes-but-still-fragmented)

but it does not have an answer.

Comment: What is the size of the table?  Small tables (< a full extent) will remain a mixed extent and show heavy fragmentation, even after defragmenting.

Comment: You'll probably have better luck getting an answer here:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dave.Gugg Yes, the tables are relatively small. Can you point me to some good article on MSDN about that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From MSDN:

> In general, fragmentation on small indexes is often not controllable.
>   The pages of small indexes are stored on mixed extents. Mixed extents
>   are shared by up to eight objects, so the fragmentation in a small
>   index might not be reduced after reorganizing or rebuilding the index.

This quote is from this MSDN article on [Reorganizing and Rebuilding Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858(v=sql.105).aspx).  Another good source is this MSDN article on [Understanding Pages and Extents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969(v=sql.105).aspx).